# How should I implement the backward pass through a flatten layer of a CNN?

Tags: neural-networks, convolutional-neural-networks, backpropagation, implementation

I am making a NN library without any other external NN library, so I am implementing all layers, including the flatten layer, and algorithms (forward and backward pass) from scratch. I know the forward implementation of the flatten layer, but is the backward just reshaping it or not? If yes, can I just call a simple NumPy's `reshape` function to reshape it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a simple reshape would do the trick. A flattening layer is just a tool for reshaping data/activations to make them compatible with other layers/functions. The flattening layer doesn't change the activations themselves, so there is no special backpropagation handling needed other than changing back the shape.

Answer (score 2):

The `Flatten` layer has no learnable parameters in itself (the operation it performs is fully defined by construction); still, it has to propagate the gradient to the previous layers.

In general, the `Flatten` operation is well-posed, as whatever is the input shape you know what the output shape is.

When you backpropagate, you are supposed to do an "Unflatten", which maps a flattened tensor into a tensor of a given shape, and you know what that specific shape is from the forward pass, so it is also a well-posed operation.

More formally

Say you have `Img1` in input of your `Flatten` layer

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{1,1}(x; w_{1,1}) & f_{1,2}(x; w_{1,2}) \\ 
f_{2,1}(x; w_{2,1}) & f_{2,2}(x; w_{2,2})
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So, in the output you have

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{1,1}(x; w_{1,1}) & f_{1,2}(x; w_{1,2}) & f_{2,1}(x; w_{2,1}) & f_{2,2}(x; w_{2,2})
\end{pmatrix}
$$

When you compute the gradient you have

$$
\frac{df_{i,j}(x; w_{i,j})}{dw_{i,j}}
$$

and everything in the same position as in the forward pass, so the unflatten maps from the `(1, 4)` tensor to the `(2, 2)` tensor.